# Google Firebase Realtime Database issue with p12 in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just started integration of Realtime Database in Unity. I am following this [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start)

In Configuring the SDK for the Unity Editor, its mentioned:

> If you choose to use rules that disallow public access, you will need to configure the SDK to use a service account to run in the Unity Editor. This will also allow you to impersonate end users while testing. To do this first create a new p12 file via
>
> https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=YOUR-FIREBASE-APP
>
> If you set up public access, you do not need a service account to use the database in the Unity Editor.
>   Record the generated email and password of the service account.
>
> Place the p12 file under "Editor Default Resources" within your Unity project. Next, add the following code to initialize usage of the service account.

The problem is that it does not give me the p12 file. It says it has been downloaded to your system. How can I get this p12 file and place in "Editor Default Resources"?

**Edit:**

Screenshots:

[image: Service Account Creation]

[image: Service Account Created]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase developer here and I apologize for the obtuse directions.  On that page, you will see a link for creating a service account "CREATE SERVICE ACCOUNT"

Choose that and walk through its steps.  Be sure to grant at least project editor permissions and create a p12 file if you given a choice.

To do this, you will need to be a project owner for this cloud project.

[image]

--Edit--
The download is handled by your browser.  On Chrome, you should see a tab at the bottom which lets you navigate and view the file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have updated my question and included screenshots. As you can see it says it has downloaded p12 file but I am unable to find it. Where does it download?